# swift print element in array at the indexPath.row

Tags: swift, xcode, didselectrowatindexpath

want to print string at element from array

```
var twoDimensionalArray = [
    ExpandableNames(isExpanded: false, names: ["Antiques",
        "Art",
        "Collectables",
        "Other Antiques , Art & Collectables"]),


    ExpandableNames(isExpanded: false, names: ["Baby Carriers",
        "Baby Clothing",
        "Baths",
        "Safety"]),
]


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let mm = twoDimensionalArray[indexPath.row]

  if indexPath == [1,1]{
 print("this is mm:",mm)
 }

        }
```

//print statement prints

mm is: ExpandableNames(isExpanded: true, names: ["Baby Clothing","Baths","Safety"])

i just want it to print "Baby Carriers"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `ExpandableNames` is defined something like this

```
struct ExpandableNames {
    var isExpanded: Bool
    var names: [String]
}
```

you could retrieve the first item at `indexPath.row` like this

```
if let firstName = twoDimensionalArray[indexPath.row].names.first {
    //do something with firstName 
}
```

or if you want to access an element at a specific index

```
var index = 0
let firstName = twoDimensionalArray[indexPath.row].names[index]
```

Comment: sorry Joakim Danielson i just realised this only prints the index 0 , how would i set it up so that index becomes what every index i click on? so if i click on section 1 row 1 it prints whats every the twoDimensionalArray.names is at that row?

Comment: i'm guessing i just change the have a line of code for each row and change it to index = 1 , for row 1, index = 2 , for row 2. unless there's a better way?

Comment: also i believe it should be let firstName = twoDimensionalArray[indexPath.section].names[index]    - changing it from inexPath.row to indexPath.section

Comment: I declared `index` as a var so it could be changed so the second option is probably best then. There was no mention of sections in the question so I don't see how that is relevant.

Comment: yes sorry just something I was seeking but didn't explain properly

Comment: @benpalmer661 Well it belongs in a new question and not in this one.